# Socket could not be created. Operation not permitted (udp)

Tags: python, linux, sockets, udp

I'm having trouble with this line of code that would not run without sudo.

```
try:

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)

except socket.error, msg:

    print 'Socket could not be created. Error Code: ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]

    sys.exit()
```

I get :

```
Socket could not be created. Error Code : 1 Message Operation not permitted.
```

Does anybody have a solution for this? Thanks in advance

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45127645/errno-1-operation-not-permitted-when-creating-socket  (I would mark as a duplicate, but the answer has not been accepted)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I cant create raw socket in Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826407/why-i-cant-create-raw-socket-in-ubuntu)

Comment: You need root rights on linux to acces sockets maybe have a look at this https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html